# 'Game' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, django

Getting error **'Game' object does not support item assignment**

```
games = []
for i in range(len(filterList)):
    durations = findDurationInHour(filterList[i].startDate,filterList[i].endDate)
    filterList[i]['duration'] = durations
    games.append(filterList[i])
filterList = games
```

i am trying to add duration into array object as a key. but on line

```
filterList[i]['duration'] = durations
```

getting error: 'Game' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Shouldn't this be `filterList[i].duration = durations`? That being said, without the relevant models, and some notion of what `findDurationInHour` does, it is very hard to  help you.

Comment: If @WillemVanOnsem's answer doesn't work, can you provide more info on your Game class? It is difficult to help you without it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem __findDurationInHour__ find hours between start dates

Comment: But you haven't said what `filterList` is or what it contains. It seems likely that it is a queryset; why are you trying to treat it like a list of dicts? (And also note that `for i in range(len(something))` is almost never the right thing to do in Python.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes you are right. it is a queryset; i am new in python can you please provide right way to do in python?

Answer (score 0):

You set attributes in Python objects with dot syntax. And note there is no need to build up a separate `games` list; you can modify items in `filterList` directly.

```
for item in filterList:
    durations = findDurationInHour(item.startDate, item.endDate)
    item.duration = durations
```

Although I must say that it sounds like `findDurationInHour` should be a method on the model, in which case there would be no need to have this loop at all; you could call it on the items when you need to (presumably in the template.)

Comment: getting error -  'int' object has no attribute 'utcoffset' at __item.duration = durations__

Comment: Well that is not related to this. You need to update the question - or ask a new one - with the full traceback and the code of whatever method is causing the problem (presumably `findDurationInHour`).

Comment: from __findDurationInHour__ returning integer. not error from this function